# Failed to build the app. Error: Build Failed. No push access to specified image repository. Try running with `--default-repo` flag

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm getting this error "Failed to build the app. Error: Build Failed. No push access to specified image repository. Try running with `--default-repo` flag." while deploying to cloud run in GCP

[image: Error screenshot]

I'm trying to store the build image in ASIA region.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, it seems that it derives from the misconfiguration in the name of the container that will be hosted in Google Cloud, for example, at the time of deploy you are asked to select a project in Google Cloud, mine let's say it will be called "MyProject-123", well, in the review settings, when you must give a name to the container that will host your service the following structure is suggested:

```
gcr.io/<The-Name-Of-My-Project>/<The-Name-Of-My-Service>.
```

at the beginning I thought that this same string would be the URL string through which I would access my service (this is not so), then I changed this string for something more aesthetic.

For example:

```
gcr.io/cloudapi/<The-Name-Of-My-Service>.
```

When running the Docker daemon **it could not find inside the Google Cloud project a folder or container called**  so **it will suggest you to define a **--default-repo.**
To fix this, **simply leave the name of the container as suggested by Google Cloud and Cloud Run**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that with

```
gcloud auth login
```

I believe the extension was trying to deploy to the correct project using the wrong user.